# Why does polars finish method of SerWriter trait require mutable reference

Tags: dataframe, rust, rust-polars

In the definition of polars SerWriter trait:

```
pub trait SerWriter<W>
where
    W: Write,
{
    fn new(writer: W) -> Self;
    fn finish(&mut self, df: &mut DataFrame) -> Result<(), PolarsError>;
}
```

The `finish` method require a `mut` reference. Since the method is supposed to write a `DataFrame` to a buffer it should leave the underlying data unchanged. This makes it harder to interact with other serialization frameworks such as `serde` which in the `serialize` method of its `Serialize` trait requires an immutable reference. Is there any other solution than to call `.clone()` in case one has just a regular reference?